# Format Date in Android wear watchface

Tags: wear-os

I am trying to format the date in Android wear watchface as "dd-MMM" using this code

```
mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(DigitalWatchFaceService.this);
mDateFormat.setCalendar(mCalendar);
mDateFormat.format("dd-MMM");
```

However, I get this error which is pointing to the last line of above code.

> 12-20 04:32:37.896 5616-5616/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.example.android.wearable.watchface, PID: 5616
>                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date
>                                                                                             at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:302)
>                                                                                             at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.android.wearable.watchface.watchface.DigitalWatchFaceService$Engine.initFormats(DigitalWatchFaceService.java:290)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.example.android.wearable.watchface.watchface.DigitalWatchFaceService$Engine.onCreate(DigitalWatchFaceService.java:235)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:875)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1166)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem is that `java.text.DateFormat.format()` doesn't take a format string as a parameter - it takes a `Date` object. To specify a format string, either use `android.text.format.DateFormat` like this:

```
mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(DigitalWatchFaceService.this);
String output = mDateFormat.format("dd-MMM", mCalendar);
```

or use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
String output = mDateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
```

[code was typed in here freehand, so not guaranteed bug-free!]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply format it like this

mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
        Date mDate;

This will get it from the current context format:

```
mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(DigitalWatchFaceService.this);
```

The full code is:

```
        java.text.DateFormat mDateFormat;
            mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");

        private void initFormats() {
            mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
            mDateFormat.setCalendar(mCalendar);
        }
```

draw it somewhere:

```
                canvas.drawText(
                        mDateFormat.format(mDate),
                        mXOffset, mYOffset + mLineHeight * (float)1.5, mDatePaint);
```

You need to call above in your onCreate:

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
            }
            super.onCreate(holder);


            Resources resources = DigitalWatchFaceService.this.getResources();

            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            mDate = new Date();
            initFormats();
        }
```